# How to rapidly publish web role cloud service, uploading only binaries, avoiding wholly restarting the VM?

Tags: wcf, azure, publishing, azure-powershell, azure-management-api

Possible ways to accomplish it:

1. Creating dedicated WCF service for this purpose (currently my favorite option)
2. Using the REST API?
3. Azure PowerShell?

### Explanation:

Publishing a web-role cloud-service takes about 10 minutes. It's much too long during development - I try to do as much as I can offline, unit-test-ish and modular, but it's just impossible to completely avoid development cycles altogether with the VM.

Apparently, the long time is mostly a result of the machine being wholly restarted, so I'm trying to find an ***automatic*** solution, like uploading and installing the binaries.

1. What is the best way to accomplish it?
2. What do you think? would it cut at least 50% of the publishing time?
3. Do you expect any critical problems?

Comment: Please clarify 2 things 1) When you say `web worker`, you mean `Web Role/Worker Role (i.e. Cloud Services)`? and 2) Do you want to speed it up just for testing purposes or do you want it in production as well?

Comment: @GauravMantri - thanks, I updated with clarification - yes, it's a `web-worker`, and yes, it's only for development

Comment: Thanks. One more question .... Does you cloud service has both Web and Worker roles or just a Web Role?

Comment: @GauravMantri - Currently only web role, but everything is according to our need of course.

Answer (score 0):

**The solutions proposed below are *definitely against best practices* and should NEVER-EVER be used in production environment.**

If your objective is to quickly test your changes in your development environment, there are two ways you can go about it.

1. **Enable RDP and copy your modified binaries or other files directly in the appropriate folders on the VM**. You could enable `Remote Desktop` on your web role and copy the files manually in appropriate folders.
2. **Use Web Deploy**: This will only work for web roles in your project but you could enable `Web Deploy` on your `Web Roles` and use that to make faster deployment. Please see this link for more details on how to use this feature: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683672.aspx.

Comment: Option 1 is not automatic (imagine the cycle: code change -> rebuild -> ***[manually-copying-files-if-you-see-what-I-mean...]*** -> test -> all over again...). option 2 is not possible for cloud-service, only for web-app, sadly...

Comment: Option 2 is certainly available for cloud services (though only web roles). Please check the link in my answer. I agree that Option 1 is not automatic but I think it is better than redeploying the package.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, and it is even enabled in my deployment settings - and it still takes 10 minutes, albeit it is enabled.

Comment: Hmmm...I must admit I never tried it. I have only read about it that it is super fast and is meant for quickly deploying and testing the code changes in cloud services. Sorry about this.